# SELECT MySQL substring from certain phrase, including the phrase itself

Tags: mysql

Sample string:

'watches from 100 €. Best selection in internet'

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_title`, ' €', -1)
```

returns 'Best selection in internet'. But how to return '€. Best selection in internet', so the € will be included in the output? I am trying to update the meta titles and the price is based on the actual product for sale.

Comment: Why are you using the substring function if you want to print the full field? Can you provide your entire query?

Comment: Er.  `CONCAT('€', SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_title, ' €', -1))`?  Very very strange requirement indeed.

Comment: thank you, @eggyal, now I understand. I admit, it was a bit stupid question.

Comment: Suppose that you don't want only the € but also the price in front of it? That would be a very viable question.